# Concat variable name in angular cli using ngFor

Tags: angular, angular-cli

using ngFor and its index I need to call unique variables. How can I concat the variable name in the HTML using the value of the index?

I need to reference:
    var1
    var2
etc...

Example code is as follows:

```
<div *ngFor="let project of _data; let i = index">
  {{project.name}}
  <button (click)="var1 = !var1">Toggle Me</button>
</div>
```

Thanks for any advice

Comment: Why you want to do this in HTML?

Comment: Hi - because the html template is rendering the data and that button and its clickEvent value are part of the data rendering - how would you suggest an approach? Thanks

Comment: I would make something like `(click)="contactValues(i, project.name, project.name2)"` and in the component a function `contactValues(_index: number, _value1: string, _value2: string) { this._data[i].concat = `${_value1} ${_value2}` }`. Something like this I'm not sure what you want to do with the concat value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manage it via creating a new property in project

```
<div *ngFor="let project of _data; let i = index">
  {{project.name}}
  <button (click)="project['status'] = !project['status']">Toggle Me</button>
</div>
```

Comment: hi That works great for my scenario - however in future is there a way to concat a variable using the index?

Comment: the [] is using to write [expresion], e.g. project['var'+i] or project['status'] if is a "fixed" expresion use dot notation: better write project.status than project['status']